# Does "mysql_query() or die()" leave open mysql connection?

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, die

Does `mysql_query() or die()` leave open mysql connection?
My thought is that it calls `die()` but it never calls `mysql_close()` on the connection...

Thanks.

Comment: Just a word of advice on this though, instead of dying out like that , you should instead have some logic to show the error to the user versus showing them a nasty white page with a small amount of text. The side benefit of this is that you can actually close the connection after the failed query.

Comment: keep your connection open by using mysql_pconnect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [mysql_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php) docs:

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution. See also freeing resources

Answer (score 5):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually
>   necessary, as non-persistent open
>   links are automatically closed at the
>   end of the script's execution.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.
Read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php):

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually
>   necessary, as non-persistent open
>   links are automatically closed at the
>   end of the script's execution.

Comment: heh, 3 same answers simultaneously :)